# How to rescale screen with awesome

Tags: awesome-wm

After installed awesome wm, I used xrandr to change my resolution with
`xrandr -s 1920x1080`

but the screen seem to be at 50% of scale
Tried to restart awesome wm but not working

So how do I re-scaling it to 100%

Scaling resolution to 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AwesomeWM does not handle screen scaling or resolution in any way. Sometime you need a magic `xrandr` incantation. Also make sure you set the DPI correctly and the font scale in Qt, Chome/Firefox and GTK settings. The classic value is `96`.